# MeteorJs, unable to get method.call return value outside of the method

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have following autoform hook code. How can I get value outside of method.call.

My problem is that when I run method.call, then 'chi' value is undefined. Whereas, on server there is '1' record.But chi doesn't get 'myResult' value. If I comment out the method.call and return 'Gogo', then 'chi' gets this value correctly. Can some one guide me what I am doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Code:

```
    before: {
    method: function(doc) {
        var retVal = false ;
        var pai = Q.fcall(function(){
            if(!_.isEmpty(doc) && _.pick(doc, 'name') ) {
                console.log('Ist level, true condition: ', doc);
                return true;
            }
            else{
                console.log('Ist level, false condition: ', doc);
                return false;
            }
        })
            .then(function(check){
                console.log('Check value: ', check);

                if( check ){
                 Meteor.call('CategoryNameAvailable', doc.name, function (error, result) {

                        console.log('Returned result from server', result);
                        if (!result) {
                            if(Contexts.Category.keyIsInvalid('name')){
                                Contexts.Category.resetValidation('name');
                            }
                            console.log('Returned result from server inside if condition  ', result);
                            Collections.Category.simpleSchema().namedContext("CategoryInsertForm").addInvalidKeys([{
                                name: "name",
                                type: "notUnique"
                            }]);

                            console.log('Doc value in meteor call function: ', doc);
                            Session.set('retVal', true);
                            console.log('retVal value in meteor call function: ', retVal);
                        }
                        return 'myResult';
                    });
                    // return 'Gogo';
                    /*  Meteor call End  */
                }

            })
            .then(function(chi){
                console.log('Chi value: ', chi);
            })
            .done();

        console.log('Pai value-2: ', pai);

    }  /* End of  method */
} /* End of 'before' hook */
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check this out https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method

It might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you could add in the file where you're defining your method? I had a similar problem recently attempting to do something similar, and it had to do with the formatting of my Method definition.

For me it was misplacing where I was returning data within my method definition. In another instance of another similar problem, I wasn't subscribing to the Collection on the client side.

If thats not the issue, and your call is returning data correctly, its *only* not passing it outside of the context of the call, you could try and use Session.set to define a session variable that can then be called whenever you need the data.

Its going to be difficult to tell exactly whats going on though without the context of the Method definition.

Comment: Problem is that 'if' condition completes its execution before method return value from server. So some speed issues :) 'if' is more speedy than method.call.